# Deleting leftover git refs from old project

Tags: git, gitlab

I was working on a project and now i want to upload the folder to another.

I am trying to run the following commands:

```
cd existing_folder
git init
git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:myname/project.git
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin master
```

However, i get the error:

```
error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'gitlab.com:myname/project.git'
```

When i try to push the existing folder.

I had old remotes left over from a different repo. I deleted those with:

```
git remote rm origin
```

However, i notice that the refs still give me incorrect data when i try to run

```
git show-ref
```

I get

```
long code refs/heads/branch-from-old-project
long code refs/heads/branch2-from-old-project
long code refs/stash
```

Stash is probably because i was using sourcetree before.

Any help would be appreciated here. Is there a way to reset all of these connections from the old project? I tried reinstalling but nothing was changed. I think these refs are perhaps the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you said `git init` in a folder that already has a `.git` repository? That probably doesn't do what you think it does. If the goal is to throw away the existing `.git` repo and start over, you literally need to throw it away. But of course you will lose all existing history!

Comment: How can i throw away the repo? The project was connected to a remote gitlab repository that is not mine. The files themselves only have .gitignore and gitlab-ci.yaml

Comment: You lost me. :) You said "I had old remotes left over from a different repo". If there was no `.git` folder, that's impossible. You may be _inside_ an existing git repo if there is not one right in front of you.

Comment: When i ran remote -v i had origin set to the old repository. I then removed it. Thats what i meant. Sorry,im new at this. If theres any other way to clarify this im glad to give all info

Comment: But right after a `git init` on a folder without a `.git` folder before, `remote -v` would be empty.

Comment: I honestly have no idea why .git isnt there. I even just reran git init and the old remote's i added are still there.

Comment: what does `git rev-parse --absolute-git-dir` say?

Comment: C:/Users/User/Desktop/Project/.git

I assume that means i was wrong about the .git dir not being there? Should i just remove it with rm .git?

Comment: `rm -rf .git` should do it, or show invisibles and throw it in the trash. But since you said `.git` is not there I'm not strongly inclined to trust much of what you say at this point. The `git` dir may be there but are _you_ there? What does `pwd` say (I assume that works on Windows).

Comment: Im there, its just been a long day, sorry. Pwd gives

C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project

I was checking if .git exists with dir command. Didnt consider the idea that the folder might not be visible

Comment: Then I'd say my answer is right. Throw away the `.git` folder, say `git init` and the initial dance, and you should be ready to push.

Comment: Oh one more thing! Do a `git branch` to make sure you are actually on `master`, as it might be called something else such as `main` by default. You can't push origin master if there is no master.